# Como colocar a tabela de bootstrap sobre uma imagem de fundo?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Estou fazendo um cadastro de times usando a tabela do *bootstrap*, onde a cada partida cadastrada, é gerada uma nova linha com os dados, o problema é que a tabela não fica sobre a imagem de fundo.

[image: Tela do site]

A tabela não aparece caso a tela esteja cheia, só aparece quando a diminuo.

[image: Tela do site num tamanho menor]

*HTML* e *PHP*

```
<body>
    <div class="fundo-externo">
        <div id="fundo">
            <img src="../images/ball1.jpg"/> <!-- alt="Uma bola de futebol sobre um gramado" -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <header class="masthead clearfix navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="logo col-xs-12 col-md-2">
            <img src="../images/drawing2.png" width="35%"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 inner">
            <div class="nav justify-content-center m-auto">
                <h3 class="titulo"> ÁREA DE CADASTRO DE TIMES </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

// Área para cadastro
<form action="queryeconfirm.php" method="POST"> <br>
        <div class="container-fluid mt-5" >
            <div class="row mb-5">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-3"> </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 mb-5">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only"> Time 1 </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <img src="../images/icon.png" width="12px"/> </span>
                        <input type="text" name="time1" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Primeiro time" required="" autofocus>
                    </div> <br> 

                    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only"> Time 2 </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <img src="../images/shield.png" width="12px"/> </span>
                        <input type="text" name="time2" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundo time" required="">
                    </div> <br> <br>

                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block" type="submit"> Adicionar times </button>
                </div> <!-- /container -->  
            </div> <!-- /container -->
        </div> <!-- /container -->
        <!-- LINK: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/ (Navs BOOTSTRAP) -->
    </form> 


    // Onde busco os dados no banco
    <?php
        /* Faz a conexao */
        include("../conn/conexao.php");

        $buscar = "SELECT * FROM tb_time";
        $exe = mysqli_query($conexao, $buscar) or die("Ocorreu um erro ao mostrar os dados.");

        // Parte fixa da tabela, o cabeçalho
        echo "
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='table-responsive'>
                <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> ID </th>
                            <th> Time 1 </th>
                            <th> Time 2 </th>
                            <th> Atualizar </th>
                            <th> Apagar </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>";

        // Onde são geradas as partidas que foram cadastradas
        $cont = 0;
        while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($exe)){
             // Caso o $cont seja par, ele irá receber a cor "white", caso ímpar, ele receberá "d2feff"
             $color = $cont%2 == 0 ? "white" : "d2feff"; 
                echo "  
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>".$linha['id']."</th>
                            <td>".$linha['time1']."</td>
                            <td>".$linha['time2']."</td>
                            <td align='center'> <a href='update.php?id=".$linha['id']."'> <img src='../images/update.png'> </a> </td>
                            <td align='center'> <a href='delete.php?id=".$linha['id']."'> <img src='../images/delete.png'> </a> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>";
             $cont++;
        }

        // Fechando a tabela
        echo "  
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class='container'>
                2017 - Ester A. Patricio
            </div>";
    ?>

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-beta/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"> </script>
    <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/  -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Meu *CSS*

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}  


.titulo{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    margin-right:25%;
    font-family:monospace;
    font-size:220%;
}

#fundo-externo {
    overflow: hidden; /* para que não tenha rolagem se a imagem de fundo for maior que a tela */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* criamos um contexto para posicionamento */
}

#fundo {
    position: fixed; /* posição fixa para que a possível rolagem da tela não revele espaços em branco */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#areaLogin{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

#aqui{
    color:blue-sky;
}
```

Comment: É porque a imagem de fundo tem uma altura limitada.

Comment: A propósito, "Bota Fogo" está errado, o correto seria "Botafogo" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou fazer um exemplo usando a tabela do `bootstrap` aí você precisa adequar ao seu projeto.

Utilizei uma `div` ao exemplo apenas para exemplificar, pode ser o `body` da página.

> Lembrando que no bootstrap quando precisa subscrever o css nativo precisa inserir `!important` ao final de cada atributo.

```
background-color: rgba(230, 230, 125, 0.2) !important;
```

```css
table {
  min-width: 100% !important;
  position: relative !important;
  background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.3) !important;
}

table tbody tr:hover{
  background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.5) !important;
  color: white;
}

#background {
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
padding: 50px;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/800/500');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="background">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Média</th>
        <th>Gols</th>
        <th>Vitórias</th>
        <th>Mundial</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Vitor</td>
        <td>Botafogo</td>
        <td>12%</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alex</td>
        <td>Flamengo</td>
        <td>5%</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Theodoro</td>
        <td>Palmeiras</td>
        <td>17%</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>!</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67950/discussion-on-answer-by-wmomesso-como-colocar-a-tabela-de-bootstrap-sobre-uma-im)

Comment: @Maniero sim, normalmente eu clico em continuar está conversa no chat, mas exclusivamente neste caso o botão não foi habilitado.